# Openssl certificate verification stricter/different than browsers?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I've put together a Linux (Centos 7) server to serve eye-n-sky.net.

Serving content from that site to browsers on Win10 and Linux systems works beautifully.  However, when I use openssl to access the site,

```
openssl s_client -connect eye-n-sky.net:443
```

the site certificate is rejected,

```
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

I've concluded that the way a browser verifies the certificate is different from what openssl does.  Am I on the right track?

I've tested this on three different openssl instances (Debian, Centos, FreeBSD) and have consistent results.

Openssl as a client to other sites, e.g. [www.godaddy.com](http://www.godaddy.com), microsoft.com, work fine, being able to verify the certificate against the installed CA chain.

Believing that I was missing a CA cert, I used the -CAfile option to specify the possibly missing cert, to no effect.

What am I missing?  I'm guessing that openssl has a stricter verification discipline, but I don't know where that gets configured.

Thanks,
Andy

---

Summary: yes, eye-n-sky was providing only it's cert when it needed to include the intermediate and root certs.

However, it took me forever to figure out that my Apache version did not support including the chain in the server cert file.  Instead, I had to provide the chain file separately in an SSLCertificateChainFile directive.

Comment: In short: the site fails to provide intermediate certificates. Browsers often successfully work around this, but other TLS stacks do not even try. On top of this the configuration of the site is broken and insecure in many other ways, see [the SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=eye-n-sky.net).

Comment: Beautiful!  Didn't think to have SSLLabs take a look!  Improving the security of the site was something I needed to do down the line, and the report provides a solid outline of what I have to do.

Comment: Bingo, Steffen!  Your note that browsers cache intermediate certs from other verifications explains it perfectly.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL's command-line `s_client` utility has nothing built in to validate the server's certificate.  Browsers have a built-in list of trusted certificates to verify the server certificate against.

You have to supply the trusted certificates using options such as `-CAfile file` or `-CApath directory`.  Per the [OpenSSL 1.1.1 `s_client` man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-s_client.html):

> **-CApath directory**
>
> The directory to use for server certificate verification. This
> directory must be in "hash format", see [`verify(1)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/verify.html) for more
> information. These are also used when building the client certificate
> chain.
>
> **-CAfile file**
>
> A file containing trusted certificates to use during server
> authentication and to use when attempting to build the client
> certificate chain.

Note the use of words such as "certificate chain".  If you go to [godaddy.com](https://www.godaddy.com/) you'll see that the server's cert is for `*.godaddy.com`, but it was signed by `Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2`, and that intermediate certificate was signed by `Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2` - a different certificate.  There's a total of three certificates in that chain.

[Verify return code 21 is "no signatures could be verified because the chain contains only one certificate and it is not self signed"](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/verify.html), so if your CA file only had the certificate from `Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2` and not the one from `Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2`, OpenSSL would see from the server's cert itself that it was signed by `Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2` and could go no further - it doesn't have that cert to see who signed it.

Comment: OpenSSL has builtin _logic_ to use a default CA file and directory, see `-no-CAfile` and `-no-CApath` on that same man page. _Upstream_ OpenSSL doesn't _include_ any certs in this default location, leaving it up to builders, packagers, installers, or admins; the **packages on CentOS and Debian at least do provide a set of default certs** that are at least reasonable; I'm not sure about FreeBSD but likely it does.

Comment: Andrew, ah, now I understand.  It appeared that s_client was able to validate other sites with complex cert chains, but now I realize that the entire chain was provided by the server.  s_client only traversed the chain to verify each subject-issuer relationship and that the last cert was a root.  My server did not provide any intermediates and so could go nowhere in the verification process.